# distinguishing similar windows when there are some when using unity

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Unity, how to tell which window is the one I want when switching?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39938/in-unity-how-to-tell-which-window-is-the-one-i-want-when-switching)

If i have similar windows of the same program i'm having big problems to click on the one i want because their content is similar and i can't recognize it when i click to see the list of windows.

If i had an ordered list of windows it would be easy to select the first or the third but by default at least the order changes whenever you click on one window.

Any ideas about how to solve that problem? If i can't i think i will continue with the classic desktop.

Answer (score 0):

In the launcher left of the icon of your program there are multiple small arrows - as many as you have windows open. If you click precisely on those, a cascade of them will appear on the screen (very similar to what happens when pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>). Clicking on one of the windows will give it highlight.

To display the titles in this view as joris said:

1. Enable the **Text** and **Scale addons** plugin in Compiz Config Settings Manager
2. In the **Scale addons** plugin of CCSM: set Appearance -> Window title -> Window title display to All windows

[image: precise clicking on the left arrows]

Comment: Can you move this answer to the original question? It'd be more useful there now that this has been closed as a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Just clicking on the icon in the Launcher will bring up all the open windows for that icon on your current workspace, you do not need to click the arrows. A further click will show all open windows for that icon on all workspaces.